# Django TemplateSyntaxError :- How access Dictionary values for iteration?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-templates

I have one list and dictionary. Where list values are keys of dictionary. Want to display this data on html page like there will be 3 tables first is Per page B&W print, second "Per page front and back B&W print" and third Per page Color print as in `tableTitle` list. now in  table data will come from respective key of `complext_dict`. so final output should like this:-

table 1:- **Per page B&W print** and table rows are 2 first abcd.pdf and second abc,pdf.

table 2:-**Per page front and back B&W print** and table rows are zero

table 3:-**Per page Color print** and table row is one rp.pdf

```
 tableTitle = ["Per page B&W print",
                "Per page front and back B&W print",
                "Per page Color print",]


    complex_dict = {'Per page B&W print': ['abcd.pdf', 'abc.pdf'],
                    'Per page front and back B&W print': [], 
                     'Per page Color print': ['Rp.pdf']}
```

Here is the HTML template

```
{% for title in tableTitle %}
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>{{title}}</p>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Documet Name</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for file in complexDict.title%}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                                    <td>{{file}}</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

** app/views.py **

```
def userDashboard(request):
   tableTitle = ["Per page B&W print",
                    "Per page front and back B&W print",
                    "Per page Color print",]

  complex_dict = {'Per page B&W print': ['abcd.pdf', 'abc.pdf'],
                  'Per page front and back B&W print': [], 
                  'Per page Color print': ['Rp.pdf']}

   return render(request, "action/userDashboard.html" , {"complex_Dict":complex_Dict, "tableTitle":tableTitle})
```

Answer (score 1):

to itterate a dict inside template you can use something like this

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
  <td>{{key}} - {{value}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want to iterate over value of each key. If u see in code each value is list. And for maintaining sequencial access of dictionary i have list of keys tableTitle.